# How modify the word boundary that includes '-' as a word character

Tags: ios, regex, swift

I'd like to capture a passcode that is between 6 and 8 digits long.

I'd like to match:
*123-4567* and
*12-34-56-78*

And fail:
*1234567890* and *123-456-7890*

As it stands I'm using `(\\b(?:\\d[-,\\h]?+){5,7}\\d\\b)`
This successfully knocks back *1234567890*, but gives a partial match on *123-456-7890*. Is there a way for the word boundary to include hyphens within it's count?

Comment: @stribizhev Updated, although I'm perfectly happy to take a PCRE/PHP solution as it's an easy conversion.... I think.

Comment: I think it'd be much easier if you remove the hyphens before matching against the regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lookarounds:

```
(?<!-)\b\d(?:[-,\h]?\d){5,7}(?!-)\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xN1pG2/1)

Swift regex uses ICU flavor, so both the lookbehind and a lookahead will work. The `(?<!-)` lookbehind makes sure there is no `-` before the digit that starts a new word (or after a word boundary), and `(?!-)` lookahead makes sure there is no `-` after the 8th digit right at the word boundary.

Do not forget to use double backslashes.

As @AlanMoore suggests, the word boundaries and `-`-lookarounds can be substituted with lookarounds `(?<![\w-])` and `(?![\w-])`. This will make the regex a bit more efficient since there will be only one position to be checked once at the start and end:

```
(?<![\w-])\d(?:[-,\h]?\d){5,7}(?![\w-])
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/rS3hM0/1)

Comment: ...or simply replace the word boundaries with `(?<![\w-])` and `(?![\w-])`.

Comment: @AlanMoore: yes, it also works, and is a bit more efficient. I guess `not \w around` lookarounds are not that important here since there are digits at both ends of the pattern, and `\b`s won't harm.

Answer (score 1):

Not an exact literal answer, but an alternative native Swift solution

```
enum CheckResult {
  case Success(String), Failure
}

func checkPassCode(string : String) -> CheckResult
{
  let filteredArray = string.characters.filter{ $0 != "-" }.map{ String($0) }
  return (6...8).contains(filteredArray.count) ? .Success(filteredArray.joinWithSeparator("")) : .Failure
}

checkPassCode("123-4567") // Success(1234567)
checkPassCode("12-34-56-78") //  Success(12345678)
checkPassCode("1234567890") // Failure
checkPassCode("123-456-7890") // Failure
```